# Есть способ скрыть печатную клавиатуру пользователя?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telebot

Возможно ли отключить печатную способность клавиатуры пользователя чтобы остались только кнопки а пользователь не мог писать боту от руки?

Answer (score 0):

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '_', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())

Comment: Это как скрыть кнопки а мне нужна клавиатура